# Hall's Marriage Theorem for correspondence

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $A=\{A_1,....A_n\}$ be a collection of subsets of a finite set $X$. A selection for $A$ is the image of an injective function $f:A\to X$ such that $   f(A_i)\in A_i$  for every  $A_i\in A$.

Hall's marriage theorem shows that ,  $A$ has a selection if and only if for each subset $S\subseteq A$,

$$|S|\leq |\cup_{i\in S} A_i|.$$

I wonder if it is possible to generalize this result and obtain a similar condition for a choice correspondence $f:A\rightrightarrows X $ that selects for each $A_i$ more than one elements, i.e. $f(A_i)\subset A_i$ and $|f(A_i)|=2$ and all selected elements are distinct.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a straightforward extension. Instead of the sequence
$$A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$$
consider the sequence
$$A_1,A_1,A_2,A_2,\ldots,A_n,A_n.$$
The Hall condition for this sequence amounts to
$$\left|\bigcup_{i\in S}A_i\right|\ge2|S|.$$

Comment: Great. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @sam This doesn't work very well with your (incorrect) definition of a choice function. You should define a choice function as an injection $f:\{1,2,\dots,n\}\to X$ instead of an injection $f:\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}\to X$ for just this reason, that you don't want to require the sets $A_i$ to be distinct.